# Selector using element id stored in a var?

Tags: jquery

I've stored the id of an element as a string, I want to get it using a jquery selector, like:

```
var theid = $('#test').attr('id');

... later ...

$(theid).remove();
```

what's the right syntax for running the selector using the string variable which contains the id of the element I want to remove?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you ever do this? you have to have the id to query for the id attribute? why not skip a step and just store '#test' in theid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$('#'+theid).remove()`

Answer (score 4):

```
var theid = $('#test').attr('id');
```

.. what? How is this any different than:

```
var theid = 'test';
```